# Need to add proxy to URLConnection in scribe

Tags: java, oauth, proxy, scribe

I am using scribe to obtain an accessToken. This works fine in a normal environment, but sometimes, I must use a proxy to obtain a connection. However, in scribe, the URLConnection (actually HTTPURLConnection) is down in Request.java and there is no access to it. So I must override many methods just to be able to set the proxy on the URLConnection.

Has anyone used scribe in an environment where a proxy is required? How did you get to the URLConnection to set the proxy?

It seems like the accessors on the Request class and the Response class could be changed to allow this, or some getters could be added to Request, but I suspect there are some reasons why this is not already the case.

How about providing a way to set a proxy on the URLConnection?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into:

- [Use scribe behind a proxy](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/FAQ#can-i-use-scribe-behind-a-proxy)
- [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

There is a third link on the scribe FAQ that SE won't let me post.
Hope you are using java 1.5 or superior.